# Conflicting JQuery animations

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm trying to animate the scrolling to a div while animating the height of said div at the same time. Both the scroll and animate work independently, but not at the same time. I assume they're conflicting somehow. Any ideas?

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $(".hublot").offset().top}, 500);
  $(".hublot").animate({height:$(window).height()}, 500, 'easeInOutQuart');
}, 500);
```

Comment: you want the scroll to finish and the height animation to start afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate all at once and not separately, something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $("html,body").animate({
       scrollTop: $(".hublot").offset().top, 
       height: $(window).height()
    }, duration: 500,
    specialEasing: {
       height: "easeInOutQuart"
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: I'm using different selectors. Could this be changed to accommodate that?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using queue.
Couldn't figure out how to write both easing and queue in shorthand though.

```
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $(".hublot").offset().top}, 500, false);
    $(".hublot").animate({height:$(window).height()}, {duration: 500, easing:"easeInOutQuart", queue: false});
```